# ...Array(something) in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am following some react tutorial and I having tough time figuring our the array method here.

So this is what we are doing

We have a state (State from react but even if you don't know, you can still follow) which we pass to child component

The state looks like this

```
state = {
    ingredient: {
      salad: 1,
      bacon: 1,
      cheese: 2,
      meat: 2
    }
  }
```

and we pass like this

```
  <Burger ingredient={this.state.ingredient}/>
```

Now In child component, We do something like this

```
  let transformedIngrident = Object.keys(props.ingredient) 

 transformedIngrident = transformedIngrident.map(igKey => { 
    return [...Array(props.ingredient[igKey])] 
  })
```

Now, I haven't previously used Array method and I am unable to understand what it does

Here, It is console.logging `//[Array(1), Array(1), Array(2), Array(2)]`

So, Can someone please explain me this line  **`return [...Array(props.ingredient[igKey])]`** (like what is `... Array()` and what does `props.ingredient[igKey]` do?

Comment: I doubt the code here is doing what it is expected to, can we get the tutorial link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the user is trying to create multiple arrays whose lengths are the values of the keys in the object `ingredient`.

Firstly, `...` is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which allows you to expand an array.

The first line `let transformedIngrident = Object.keys(props.ingredient)`  saves the keys in an array. `["salad", "bacon", "cheese", "meat"]`.

Now the `map` function is called on this array which will iterate over the values of the array.

The `Array(val)` constructor used here creates an array with the length `val` i.e. if you call `Array(2)`, a new array will be created with length 2.

For all values in `transformedIngrident`, `props.ingredient[igKey]` will provide the values 1, 1, 2 and 2 respectively. These will be treated as the lengths of the newly created arrays.

The only reason I can think of that the author of this function has used this would be to create an empty array of the desired length.

Hope this helps.

P.S. - If you are modifying the function can you please fix the spelling of `transformedIngrident`. Weird little OCD of mine.

Comment: Great explanation! I'm hoping this is some interim step, but I think you hit the nail on the head for what is happening in the question.

Comment: Thanks for that. I still can't wrap my head around why the author is doing this. The only thing I can think of is that he is using the created arrays along with some template helpers to create multiple instances of the ingredient elements.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have is an object of ingredients so you cannot map over them so what Object.keys does is it takes the keys and makes it into an array and then you can map over it..

Answer (score 0):

The `... Array()` is what is known as a Spread Operator. This is used in arrays and objects to 'Spread' out their parts. In this case it is going through each member and creating an array Object with the value that you placed in there, the `props.ingredient[igKey]`.

`props` in this case and in the case of React is the properties that have been passed to the component. So in the case of `<Burger ingredient={this.state.ingredient}/>` props contains ingredient.

So what you are ending up with is an array of Array objects there each the length of the corresponding value in `this.state.ingredient` that was passed in, such that when igKey is cheese it has created an Array object with the value assigned to cheese (2).